# Algorithms which are inherently not possible to parallelise

Tags: parallel-processing

For instance, algorithms such as LZ77 might require previous results in order to proceed but it is still possible to execute them in parallel, at least to some extent (e.g. http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jshun/dcc2013-final.pdf).

Are there any specific, real-world algorithms which have to be executed only sequentially?

Comment: Do you mean absolutely cannot be parallelised, or cannot be parellelised and show performance improvement?

Comment: If you mean cannot be sped up, see this thread: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1391/are-there-any-famous-problems-algorithms-in-scientific-computing-that-cannot-be. Also have a look at: http://www.quora.com/Computer-Science/What-are-some-of-the-famous-algorithms-in-use-which-cannot-be-parallelized

Comment: @JohnCarter Aren't they the same? Any algorithm can be parallelized, just by running the same code concurrently.. then it is successfully parallelized, just with zero performance improvement. Wow, that was pedantic.

Comment: @Thomas That's what I'm wondering.  If its just a matter of zero improvement, then the answer is yes -- one can point to lots of examples that won't provide speed up when parallelised.  If its the alternative, then it's far more theoretical.

Comment: @John I assumed that not showing any improvement is the same as not possible to parallelise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wikipedia:

> Some problems have no parallel algorithms, and are called inherently
>   serial problems.

Examples:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

You can also have a look at this thread [algorithms that cannot be sped up by parallelisation](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1391/are-there-any-famous-problems-algorithms-in-scientific-computing-that-cannot-be)

Comment: related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19643/which-algorithms-can-not-be-parallelized